# How to queue process on libGDX - Ashley ECS framework system?

Tags: timer, libgdx, 2d, game-physics

I have `GunSystem class` this system handles the processing of the weapon of my player.

```
class GunSystem extends IteratingSystem implements Gun{
   super(Family.all(GunComponent.class, ...).get());

   @Override
   protected void processEntity(Entity entity, float deltaTime) {
        updateGun();
        onReload();
        onFire();
   }

   private void updateGun() {
       // Textures, Position, Size ..
   }
}
```

By default, when the `Gun` is attach to a `Player`, the gun will automatically be reloaded. So the player can fire the gun immediately.

```
Gun gun = new Gun();
Player player = new Player();
player.setWeapon(gun)

// class:Player, method:onFire()
Gun gun = player.getWeapon();
gun.fire() // or gun.trigger();
// class:GunSystem, method:onReload();
gun.reload(); // reload the gun for half a second, before the gun can be fired again.
```

**Concerns**
Because I am using the libGDX - Ashley ECS (*Entity Component System*) Framework, I want to fully use its classes. Currently my main concern is the `GunSystem` which extends the abstract `IteratingSystem`. What do you guys may suggest on how do I locked the gun while reloading before the trigger can be pulled again.

**What I have tried**

```
// onReload
  if(gun.reload) {
        if (timer < 0.5f) {
            timer += deltaTime;
        } else {
            gun.reload(spatialX, spatialY);
            gun.reload = false;
        }
    }

// onFire
    if(gun.triggered){
        gun.fire();
        gun.triggered = false;
        gun.reload = true;
    }
```

[image]

**Problem**
On the second player touch, the `onFire` method is called even the `onReload` is still busy.

**Objectives**

- On the first player touch, the gun will be fired because it is
  already loaded. On the second player touch, if the gun is still
  loading the firing is disabled until it become ready.
- To copy the behavior of a catapult or cannon, which on every bullet fired the reloading process will start.